# Post request with raw data throwing 400 bad request on mocha

Tags: javascript, json

```
var expect=require('chai').expect;
var http=require("http");
var request = require('request');
var env = require('./environment');

describe("Callflow TestCase", function(done) {
  //this.timeout(15000);
  it("minutes field ",function(done){
    var formData = [{
        "variables":[{"name": "OpMode",
        "value":"3",
        "section": "Treatment",
        "type": "queue"}]
    }]
    var data=(JSON.stringify(formData));
    console.log(data);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
    var options={
      url:env.hostname+'variables/menus/Call%20Flow?siteName=VHT%20TITAN&queueId=VHT_Test&segmentId=6&segmentName=58897&allQueues=false&allSegments=false',
      **raw:data**,
      headers:{
        //'lastAccess':1516781803697,
        'Token':'14275bb3c2fbc60d0dac05113dac1d6bcf3ccde00cf2699c43efedd820c2660a',
        //'ttl':2592000000,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    request.post(options,function(err,res,body) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(options.raw));
      console.log(options);
      //body=JSON.parse(body);
      expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(204);
      done();
   });
  });
});
```

Note: In the place of raw if i give form, it is throwing 500 internal server error. Same Object is working fine on postman. im getting 204 no content if iam testing this case in postman.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var options = {
    ...
    form: data,
    ...
}
```

from the [doc](https://github.com/request/request#forms).

Comment: And trying with formData not as an array ?